# How to get NSDate in "dd/MM/yyyy" formate ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am working with NSDate i created one function which give Today date with "dd/MM/yyyy" format but NSDate always show "nil" value. I googled lot and also see lots of stackoverflow answer but all answer return NSString value not NSDate value so please guide me to get NSDate with given format.

```
+(NSDate*)getCurrentDate{
     NSDateFormatter *DateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];

     //Date print here
     NSLog(@"Utility CurrentDate: %@",[DateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);    
     NSString *dateString = [DateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

     NSDateFormatter *newDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
     [newDateFormatter setDateFormat:DATE_FORMAT];
     //Date print here
     NSLog(@"New Date: %@",[newDateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
     NSDate *dateFromString = [newDateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

     return dateFromString;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

The issue is here

```
NSDate *dateFromString = [newDateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Here your `dateString` is  `2014-12-11 03:41:31`, hence it is not getting formatted. You should change either `newDateFormatter` or `DateFormatter` to convert as per your requirement.

EDIT:

Replace `[DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];` with `[DateFormatter setDateFormat: DATE_FORMAT];`

**But your return date will not be in the desired way, since you are returning an `NSDate` Object. You should return a formatted string.**

Comment: Thanks for you answer i tried and return this outPut:       CurrentDate: 11/12/2014
New Date: 11/46/2014
Current Date: 2014-01-10 18:42:00 +0000
i want to return NSDate object not NSString.

Comment: @nishitpatel: see my edit, that is already mentioned... NSDate will always be there in the fixed pattern. If you want a customized format then NSString is the only way.

Answer (score 2):

You are completely misunderstanding what NSDate is and does. An NSDate is an absolute point in time. It has no format. It cannot have a format. It is absolutely impossible to have an NSDate in "dd/MM/yyyy" format or in any other format.

When you want to display a date to the user, you use NSDateFormatter to convert the NSDate into a string. In any format you like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer now i understood NSDate concept.

Answer (score 1):

check here [Convert date from string](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/date-formatters-examples-take-3.html) or you can use this methods to convert.

These all three functions you can use to format date values..

```
-(NSString*)getStringFromDate:(NSDate*)pDate withFormat:(NSString*)pDateFormat{
NSDateFormatter *dtFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dtFormatter setDateFormat:pDateFormat];
[dtFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
return [dtFormatter stringFromDate:pDate];}

-(NSDate*)getDateFromString:(NSString*)pStrDate withFormat:(NSString*)pDateFormat{
NSDateFormatter *dtFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dtFormatter setDateFormat:pDateFormat];
[dtFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
return [dtFormatter dateFromString:pStrDate];}

-(NSString*)dateStringFromString:(NSString *)dateToConver format:(NSString *)fromFormat toFormat:(NSString *)toFormat{
NSDate *date = [Helper getDateFromString:dateToConver withFormat:fromFormat];
return [Helper getStringFromDate:date withFormat:toFormat];}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below modified method in `dd/MM/yyyy format`:-

```
+(NSString*)getCurrentDate{
    NSDateFormatter *format=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];
    NSString *currentDt=[format stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDate *dt=[format dateFromString:currentDt];
    [format setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyy"];
    return [format stringFromDate:dt];
}
```